# chrome heap snapshot statistics is wrong?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging my website, Wanted to know how much actual memory it is taking after fully loaded. In chrome Inspect>memory> statistics , Total shows 21458KB but individual is not sum up to total. What does it mean ? where is the remaining memory used ?[image]